# Importing a Large Amount of Data and Searching Efficiently

Tags: java, database, performance, csv, search

I'm currently writing a program that takes in two CSVs - one containing database keys (and other information irrelevant to the current issue), the other being an asset manifest.  The program checks the database key from the first CSV, queries an online database to retrieve the asset key, then gets the asset status from the second CSV.  (This is a workaround to a stupid API issue.)

My problem is that while the CSV that is being iterated over is relatively short - only about 300 lines long usually - the other is an asset manifest that is easily 10000 lines long (and sorted, though not by the key I can obtain from the first CSV).  I obviously don't want to iterate over the entire asset manifest for every single input line, since that will take roughly 10 eternities.

I'm a fairly inexperienced programmer, so I only know *of* sorting/searching algorithms, and I definitely don't know what would be the one to use for this.  What algorithm would be the most efficient?  Is there a way to "batch-query" the manifest for all of the assets listed in the input CSV that would be faster than searching the manifest individually for each key?  Or should I use a tree or hashtable or something else I heard mentioned in other SE threads?  I don't know anything about the performance implications of any of these.

I can format the manifest as needed when it's input (it's just copy-pasted into a GUI), so I guess I could iterate over the entire manifest when it's input and make a hashtable of key:line pairs and then search *that*?  Or I could turn it into a 2D array and just search the specified index?  Those are all I can think of.

Problem is, I don't know how much time computer operations like that take, and if that would just waste time or actually improve performance.

P.s. I'm using Java for this currently since it's all I know, but if another language would be faster then I'm all ears.

Comment: How about using .hashCode() function of java, you could iterate the same number of lines that the small doc has in the document that has many lines and compare hashes, if they match continue to iterate.

Comment: @Kl3jvi Sorry, I made it sound like I was trying to do something I wasn't in my original post.  However, that's definitely something that would improve performance in a different part of my program, so I'll have to write that down.  Thanks!

Comment: The second CSV is somehow static? could you export it to a table and let the database worry about optimizations?

Comment: @marcellorvalle Yes, it's just another database exported as a CSV, because their API won't let us query it directly and the only way to export it is as a CSV.  And I probably could!  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution will be creating a `HashMap`, iterating through one of the files and add each line of that file to the `HashMap`(with corresponding key and value), then iterate through the other one and see if the created `HashMap` contains the key, if yes add the data to another`HashMap`, then after iteration return the second `HashMap`.

Imagine we have `test1.csv` file with the content such `key,name,family` as below:

```
5000,ehsan,tashkhisi
2,ali,lllll
3,amel,lllll
1,azio,skkk
```

And `test2.csv` file with the content such `key,status` like below:

```
1000,status1
1,status2
5000,status3
4000,status4
4001,status1
4002,status3
5,status1
```

We want to have output like this:

```
1 -> status2
5000 -> status3
```

Simple code will be like below:

**Java 8 Stream:**

```
private static Map<String, String> findDataInTwoFilesJava8() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map =
            Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/test2.csv")).map(a -> a.split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap((a -> a[0]), (a -> a[1])));
    return Files.lines((Paths.get("/tmp/test1.csv"))).map(a -> a.split(","))
            .filter(a -> map.containsKey(a[0]))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> map.get(a[0])));
}
```

**Simple Java:**

```
private static Map<String, String> findDataInTwoFiles() throws IOException {
    String line;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test2.csv"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lienData = line.split(",");
        map.put(lienData[0], lienData[1]);
    }
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test1.csv"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String key = line.split(",")[0];
        if(map.containsKey(key))
            resultMap.put(key, map.get(key));
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including the "Simple Java" example, because Lambda Expressions still make my head spin.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you're doing in your first example, and what that accomplishes?  I don't really understand.

Comment: Ok, so the cascading combined with lambda expressions has me really confused, since I haven't used `Stream` before.  I'm going to walk through what I think you're doing, and please correct me if I'm wrong here.  So, `Files.lines(Path p)` returns a `Stream` object.  You're then calling `Stream.map(Function f() {})`, with `new Function() { public String[] apply(Object t) { return t.split(",") }}` as the body, right?  (What is the T/Object in this?  `Stream`?)  Ok, so that returns a new `Stream<String[]>`, which you then call `.collect(Function f1, Function f2)` on, which... uh...

Comment: Ok, so `Stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(f1, f2))` turns the Stream into a `Map` given the two "parameters" - those being operations applied to every piece of data in the Stream - and then returns the `Map` instance made from the given data.  Cool!  This is what I meant by "explain", by the way, since I had to scour four different tutorial sites and sleep on it before being able to understand what was going on, and a little description of what you were actually doing would have been very helpful.

Comment: That's correct but describing `Stream` in a comment is very difficult. I did put the simple java version in my answer because I supposed that you don't know about them and describing how it works in the answer was irrelevant.